# Vampir with local mpi installation

Tags: mpi, trace, openmpi

I work on a cluster with Vampir for visualizing mpi communication. Because the cluster was lacking a MPI3 implementation, I installed OpenMPI 2.0.0 (no other flags than --prefix were used) in my home directory (works fine without Vampir). Now I don't know to properly combine my local MPI3-install with Vampir to build my program (fetchAndOpTest.f90). I tried the following:

```
vtf90 -vt:fc ~/OpenMPI2/bin/mpif90 -o fetchAndOpTestF90.x fetchAndOpTest.f90
```

(Don't know if it's important, but this gives the following warning: `/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmpi.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libmpi_f77.so, may conflict with libmpi.so.20`)

Executing my program with `~/OpenMPI2/bin/mpirun -np 2 fetchAndOpTestF90.x` results in:
`fetchAndOpTestF90.x: error while loading shared libraries: libvt-mpi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [...]`

Therefore I also tried `vtf90 -vt:fc ~/OpenMPI2/bin/mpif90 -L/opt/vampirtrace/5.14.4/lib -o fetchAndOpTestF90.x fetchAndOpTest.f90`, but it did not change the ldd-output.

EDIT: Edited LD_LIBRARY_PATH as suggested by @Harald.

`> ldd fetchAndOpTestF90.x
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc6ada9000)
        libmpi_f77.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.1 (0x00007ff8fdf2e000)
        libvt-mpi.so.0 => /opt/vampirtrace/5.14.4/lib/libvt-mpi.so.0 (0x00007ff8fdca3000)
        libvt-mpi-unify.so.0 => /opt/vampirtrace/5.14.4/lib/libvt-mpi-unify.so.0 (0x00007ff8fda18000)
        libotfaux.so.0 => /opt/vampirtrace/5.14.4/lib/libotfaux.so.0 (0x00007ff8fd810000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff8fd50c000)
        libopen-trace-format.so.1 => /opt/vampirtrace/5.14.4/lib/libopen-trace-format.so.1 (0x00007ff8fd2c4000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff8fd0ab000)
        libpapi.so.5.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpapi.so.5.3 (0x00007ff8fce57000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff8fcc53000)
        libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007ff8fc939000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff8fc633000)
        libmpi_usempi.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libmpi_usempi.so.20 (0x00007ff8fc430000)
        libmpi_mpifh.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.20 (0x00007ff8fc1df000)
        libmpi.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libmpi.so.20 (0x00007ff8fbefb000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff8fbce5000)
        libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007ff8fbaa9000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff8fb88b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff8fb4c6000)
        libmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1 (0x00007ff8fb145000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff8fe162000)
        libpfm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpfm.so.4 (0x00007ff8fadff000)
        libopen-pal.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libopen-pal.so.20 (0x00007ff8fab09000)
        libopen-rte.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libopen-rte.so.20 (0x00007ff8fa887000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff8fa684000)
        libhwloc.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.5 (0x00007ff8fa43b000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007ff8fa231000)
        libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007ff8fa026000)
        libpciaccess.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0 (0x00007ff8f9e1d000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff8f9c15000)`

Now execution throws error: `mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node cluster exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault)` (program is correct and build and execution with local MPI3 installation without Vampir runs fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems might be resolved different alternatives in order to find the libraries:

1. Statically link the application (i.e. using the `-static` flag at link time).
2. Add `${HOME}/OpenMPI2/lib` (or `/opt/vampirtrace/5.14.4/lib`?), since your MPI installation is there) to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before running the binary.
3. Use -rpath while linking your binary so that the linker automatically searches for the given directory. You can use `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,${HOME}/OpenMPI2/lib` (or `/opt/vampirtrace/5.14.4/lib`?)

**EDIT**
Notice that you point out that you have a vampirtrace installation (`/opt/vampirtrace/5.14.4`) but that is way too old (see [this](https://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/zih/forschung/projekte/vampirtrace/)) compared to OpenMPI 2.0 (see [that](https://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/announce/2016/07/0085.php)) -- there are about 3 years of difference between the two. OpenMPI has changed a lot during these years and in version 2.0 especially. This could be also related with the warning you observe -- i.e. divergence on versions. Additionally, and this are bad news regarding this question, from the last web link you'll notice that the vampirtrace embedded package within OpenMPI has been removed.

Your best alternative, IMHO, is that you give a try to vampirtrace's successor (named [Score-P](http://www.vi-hps.org/projects/score-p)) which also generates Vampir trace-files. Since OpenMPI 2.0 is very recent, you probably should need to try RC from Score-P.

Comment: I didn't build static libs so I directly went with suggestion 2. This seems to work fine (I edited ldd-output), but now execution with ` ~/OpenMPI2/bin/mpirun -np 1 fetchAndOpTest.x` throws an error: `mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node cluster exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).` (Happens also with other programsm which are all correct). Maybe the warning indicates this problem?

Comment: I'll give Score-P a try. I think under these circumstences this is the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your VampirTrace library was compiled against some other system-wide MPI implementation and by dependency pulls in its DSOs:

```
--> libmpi_f77.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.1 (0x00007ff8fdf2e000)
libmpi_usempi.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libmpi_usempi.so.20 (0x00007ff8fc430000)
libmpi_mpifh.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.20 (0x00007ff8fc1df000)
libmpi.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libmpi.so.20 (0x00007ff8fbefb000)
--> libmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1 (0x00007ff8fb145000)
libopen-pal.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libopen-pal.so.20 (0x00007ff8fab09000)
libopen-rte.so.20 => /home/USER/OpenMPI2/lib/libopen-rte.so.20 (0x00007ff8fa887000)
```

The `PMPI_*` symbols that VampirTrace uses probably get resolved by the system-wide MPI library and thus the argument pass-through of the PMPI mechanism fails. Since VampirTrace is an open-source project (unlike Vampir, which is closed-source commercial tool), you can download it from [the official site](https://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/zih/forschung/projekte/vampirtrace) and compile it using your own Open MPI build. But that won't help in your case since VampirTtrace knows nothing about the new MPI-3 RMA calls and it won't trace them (they will most likely appear as user functions in the trace).

As already advised, use Score-P instead. The release version 2.0.2 supports the entire collection of MPI-3.1 calls.

Comment: Not only vampirtrace wont know about recent additions to mpi 3/3.1 but may fail to compile due to const-ification of MPI 3.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation, Score-P did its job as wanted